# MS SQL to Oracle linked server. Invalid metadata for column

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, linked-server

I have a requirement to replicate data from a MS SQL (AWS EC2) table to an Oracle (AWS RDS) instance.  After several failed approaches, I decided to create a Linked Server in SQL to the Ora database and insert new data on a trigger event. So far, so good.

Now I am attempting to insert data into a single Oracle table from an [identical] SQL table, but receive the following error

"The OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "desora12" supplied invalid metadata for column "CREATE_DATE". The data type is not supported."

I've tried taking CREATE_DATE out of the insert statement, but receive the same error. I also tried casting and converting the CreateDate in the select statement.  Same error.

The CREATE_DATE column type in Oracle is TIMESTAMP(6). 
The corresponding CreateDate column type in SQL is nullable DateTime

There are 31 columns in the table, here is an abridged version of the insert.

```
INSERT INTO [desora12]..[DATAENTRY].[TBL_API_ITEM_TYPEID1_LBL_TEST]
       ([SITE_ID]
       ,[USER_ID]
       ,[CREATE_DATE]
       ,[TRANSFER_DATE]
       ,[TRANSFER_STATUS])
SELECT TOP 1 SiteID,
         UserID,
         CreateDate,
         TransferDate,
         TransferStatus
    FROM API.ItemDataTypeID1Label
      WHERE TransferDate is null
      AND TransferStatus is null
      AND ReturnStatus=200
```

Any help?

Comment: Edit your question and show the code that you are using.

Comment: Try to insert an MSSql datetime value into an Oracle date field.  If that succeeds, do your initial insert into a staging table and write to your production tables from a staging table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always do "pulls" to transfer data, rather than a "push" like you are doing. Pulls ensure that you aren't harming a production database when refreshing a development or test database. As far as the dates go, I struggled with the date type between Oracle and SQL Server. I eventually converted my Oracle date to text (remember I am pulling) and allowed SQL Server to automatically convert the text to date. You can see this in my call to bindvar below where I convert the Oracle date to a string.

If you are pulling from Oracle, look into DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH. It is many times faster than selecting through a database link. I am fetching 2 million records at a time,  my run time went from 4 1/2 hours to under 5 minutes.

```
   PROCEDURE bindvar (
        p_cursor   IN INTEGER
      , p_pos      IN INTEGER
      , p_value    IN VARCHAR2
    )
    AS
        l_routine   CONSTANT oracleobj_t := 'bindvar';
    BEGIN
        DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.bind_variable@intervaldata.world (p_cursor, p_pos, p_value);
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS
        THEN
            make_log_error_entry (
                p_routine => l_routine
              , p_message => cealogging.activity_log_maintenance_pkg.labels (
                                'p_cursor'
                              , p_cursor
                              , 'p_pos'
                              , p_pos
                              , 'p_value'
                              , p_value
                            )
            );
            RAISE;
    END;

 -- ***********************************************************************
    --  Fetch Interval Data
    --  Purpose:
    --    Retrieve interval data from SQL*Server
    --  Arguments:
    --    p_earliestintervaldate - earliest interval date from which data will be fetched
    --    p_latestintervaldate   - latest   interval date from which data will be fetched
    --    p_earliestlogtime      - earliest log date for which data will be fetched
    --    p_latestlogtime        - latest   log date for which data will be fetched
    --    p_maxrecords   - maximum records to fetch from SQL Server
      -- ***********************************************************************
    FUNCTION fetch_intervaldata (
        p_earliestintervaldate   IN DATE
      , p_latestintervaldate     IN DATE
      , p_earliestlogdate        IN DATE
      , p_latestlogdate          IN DATE
      , p_meterno                IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
      , p_maxrecords             IN INTEGER DEFAULT NULL
    )
        RETURN PLS_INTEGER
    AS
        l_routine   CONSTANT oracleobj_t := 'fetch_intervaldata';
        l_format    CONSTANT oracleobj_t := 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS';

        l_cnt                PLS_INTEGER;
        l_cursor             INTEGER;
        l_earliestlogdate    DATE := p_earliestlogdate;
        l_numrows            INTEGER;
        l_row                intervaldata_load%ROWTYPE;
        l_ret                PLS_INTEGER := 0;
        l_sql                VARCHAR2 (200)
            := ';select  * from  cea.fetchCisIntervalData(  ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) where interval_read is not null';
        l_latestlogtimearg   DATE;
    BEGIN

        close_databaselink (p_link => 'INTERVALDATA.WORLD');

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'truncate table intervaldata_load';

        -- set l_cnt = 1 to allow the first pass to run
        -- thereafter it is the number or records returned by the pass that will
        -- be tested for continuation
        l_cnt   := 1;

        WHILE  l_earliestlogdate <= p_latestlogdate
          AND l_cnt > 0
          AND (p_maxrecords IS NULL
            OR l_ret < p_maxrecords)
        LOOP
            make_log_entry (
                p_routine => l_routine
              , p_message => 'processing starting for ' || TO_CHAR (l_earliestlogdate, c_intervaldateformat)
            );

            l_cursor            := DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.open_cursor@intervaldata.world;
            DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.parse@intervaldata.world (l_cursor, l_sql);
            bindvar (p_cursor => l_cursor, p_pos => 1, p_value => TO_CHAR (l_earliestlogdate, l_format));
            bindvar (
                p_cursor => l_cursor
              , p_pos    => 2
              , p_value  => TO_CHAR (l_earliestlogdate + INTERVAL '6' HOUR - INTERVAL '1' SECOND, l_format)
            );
            bindvar (p_cursor => l_cursor, p_pos => 3, p_value => TO_CHAR (p_earliestintervaldate, l_format));
            bindvar (p_cursor => l_cursor, p_pos => 4, p_value => TO_CHAR (p_latestintervaldate, l_format));
            bindvar (p_cursor => l_cursor, p_pos => 5, p_value => p_meterno);
            l_cnt               := 0;

            LOOP
                l_numrows   := DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.fetch_row@intervaldata.world (l_cursor);
                EXIT WHEN l_numrows = 0
                       OR (p_maxrecords IS NOT NULL
                       AND l_ret >= p_maxrecords);
                DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.get_value@intervaldata (l_cursor, 1, l_row.meterno);
                DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.get_value@intervaldata (l_cursor, 2, l_row.interval_start);
                DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.get_value@intervaldata (l_cursor, 3, l_row.endpointid);
                DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.get_value@intervaldata (l_cursor, 4, l_row.logtime);
                DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.get_value@intervaldata (l_cursor, 5, l_row.interval_read);
                DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.get_value@intervaldata (l_cursor, 6, l_row.buy_back);
                DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.get_value@intervaldata (l_cursor, 7, l_row.phase_a);
                DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.get_value@intervaldata (l_cursor, 8, l_row.phase_b);
                DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.get_value@intervaldata (l_cursor, 9, l_row.phase_b);
                EXIT WHEN l_row.logtime > p_latestlogdate;

                INSERT INTO intervaldata_load
                VALUES l_row;

                l_cnt       := l_cnt + 1;
                l_ret       := l_ret + 1;

            END LOOP;

            DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.close_cursor@intervaldata.world (l_cursor);

            make_log_entry (
                p_routine => l_routine
              , p_message =>    LPAD (l_cnt, 10)
                             || ' records retrieved for '
                             || TO_CHAR (l_earliestlogdate, c_intervaldateformat)
                             || ' to '
                             || TO_CHAR (l_earliestlogdate + INTERVAL '6' HOUR, c_intervaldateformat)
            );

            l_earliestlogdate   := l_earliestlogdate + INTERVAL '6' HOUR;
        END LOOP;

        RETURN l_ret;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS
        THEN
            make_log_error_entry (
                p_routine => l_routine
              , p_message => 'processing ' || TO_CHAR (l_earliestlogdate, l_format)
            );
            DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.close_cursor@intervaldata.world (l_cursor);
            RAISE;
    END fetch_intervaldata;
```